# Facebook Android SDK AppEvents not recognizing users on Insights Dashboard

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-insights

How are you?

We are integrating our App with AppEvents. To do so we are following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android) guide.

We are first trying to register simple default events after user logs in and interact with the App (ie AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_ADDED_TO_CART).   As far as we could see, data is being posted ok (App Id and logged in user Access Token seems to be ok) and we get no errors on the app.

When we enter to Events section on Insights the data we sent is there but the info about the user isn't being processeed. For example, only gender and country filters with "Unknown" return results.

We are using SDK v3.23.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on Facebook Team answer:

> This is actually by design. We do not show breakdowns for events when
>   the number of unique users that have fired that event is too low. The
>   reason is that with a small number of users for a certain event, it
>   may be possible to deduce who those users are. Once the number of
>   users exceed a certain threshold, this breakdown will be available,
>   and no longer show up as "Unknown". This is threshold is currently set
>   at 100, but is subject to change.